# regex using two markers

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

If I have an entire webpage html loaded to a php variable using

```
$html = file_get_contents('URL');
```

and im writing the content of this to a file using:

```
$myFile = "localdownload.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $html);
fclose($fh);
```

AND I ALWAYS know the content I want is between

```
<div id="listing"> and <div class="cleared"></div>
```

can a regex be written to truncate everything not in between those two markings?
So it would only file write the contents in between those marks.

Any help would be so great. Thank you to everyone who has helped me in the past.

Comment: substr and strpos would work. But as people like to say what have you tried

Comment: preg_match_all('/<div id="listing">(.*?)<div class="cleared"></div>', $html, $matches);

Comment: do not use regex for this. use a dom parser. regex is really quite bad at parsing html.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
$html = preg_replace(
    '/.*?<div id="listing">|<div class="cleared"><\/div>.*$/s', '', $html );
```

This replaces everything from the start of the string up to and including `'<div id="listing">'`, and everything from and including `'<div class="cleared"></div>'` to the end of the string, with an empty string.

The `s` modifier is used so the `.` match newlines as well as all other characters.

The above assumes `<div id="listing">` and `<div class="cleared"></div>` only occur once in the string.